# How to add new field types to repeatable custom field?

Tags: custom-field, repeatable-field

By default, Joomla provides few types of fields that could be used as repeatable custom fields:

- editor
- media
- number
- text
- textarea

I want to have more fields like boolean, or maybe even more rich like "select article".

I know that there is the possibility of overriding the files, but I am a bit scared of losing them after update.

For example, I managed to add checkbox fields by adding new string to file located at:
**/plugins/fields/repeatable/params/repeatable.xml**

```
<option value="checkbox">checkbox</option>
```

How can I achieve this in an update-safe way?

Comment: Please take our [tour] while you wait for support/feedback.

Comment: The repeatable field has been deprecated in favour of using subforms.

Comment: Make copy of the full plugin, rename it and add your own fields and layouts.